# How to stop a Thread in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-threads

I'm working with threads in Java 8 and I'm using the next code:

```
 Runnable runnable = () -> {
            LOGGER.info(....);
           someCode
          };
    
          Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
          thread.start();
```

My doubt is how can I stop or interrupt the thread or it will be stopped with itself?

Any ideas?

Comment: When the method finishes running the thread is cleaned up.

Comment: If you're creating individual threads, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thread will be automatically cleaned up after the `public void run()` method exits (implementation of which is your lambda expression), and *there is no safe way* you can explicitly tell the thread to stop.

However, you can simulate the `stop` instruction, if you'll either introduce a shared flag variable, or simply create your thread by *extending* the `Thread` class, instead of passing the `Runnable` to the Thread constructor. This way you can incorporate a flag field:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    private boolean isAlive;

    public MyThread() {
        this.isAlive = true;
    }

    public synchronized void setAlive(boolean status) {
        if (status == true) {
            return;
        }
        this.isAlive = status;
        System.out.println("Stopping " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "thread..");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has been stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (isAlive) {
            System.out.println(i + " invocation in the " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "thread.");
            ++i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start(); //instruction #1
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("In the main thread...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("In the main thread...");
        thread.setAlive(false); //after this, you'll see, that the Thread running after instruction #1 doesn't exist anymore
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("In the main thread...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("In the main thread...");
    }
}
```